# Event triggered when the content in textarea is deleted

Tags: java, html, ajax, dom, wicket

I have a wicket application and need to save the data via Ajax when the content in a textarea changes. I can easily do it via "**onchange**" DOM event when content changes. But when the user deletes (by backspace or delete keys) the entire content the **onchange** event doesn't get triggered. Which event gets triggered ?

I tried **oninput**, **onkeyup** and **onchange**. All these work until there's at least 1 character left.

Wicket specific info: Version 1.5. The text area is added on to a Panel and it is added on to a DefaultDataTable. So the component is not directly added to a Form. The TextArea is wired to a PropertyModel

```
final TextArea commentsTa = new TextArea("commentsTa", new PropertyModel<String>(dataObject, "property1"));
commentsTa.setOutputMarkupId(true);
commentsTa.setRequired(true);
commentsTa.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);

 commentsTa.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {

        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
             System.out.print("Starting onchange.... ");
            System.out.print("onchange: " + commentsTa.getConvertedInput());

        }

    });
```

---

**Updates:** 
I removed the `commentsTa.setRequired(true);` from the above code and it started working. I guess the reason is that Wicket enforces validation and as a result of that onchange event does get fired.

Comment: onchange only fires when element loses it focus(user clicks outside, tabs out, etc..)

Comment: Although Wicket may generate JavaScript, JavaScript is irrelevant to the problem here. It's a Wicket issue. I've removed the irrelevant tag (and added the Java tag). (Note: `input` is indeed fired at the JavaScript layer when you use backspace, etc., in a `textarea`: https://jsfiddle.net/tmfoau16/)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Wicket just registers listeners for JavaScript events. If there is no JavaScript event then there is no Ajax call made by Wicket. So, I don't understand why this is an issue in Wicket. I've modified your JSFiddle to use `change` event and it properly fires even after removing the whole content and moving out of the textarea.

Comment: @martin-g: Of course it does, that's when `change` fires. But the OP specifically said above they've tried `oninput`. It's a Wicket issue if `oninput` didn't work, since at the browser level, `input` is definitely fired in that case.

Comment: i always suggest to use `OnChangeAjaxBehavior`

Comment: @martin-g I have identified the issue; it's because of the setRequired(true). Once I removed,  it started working. Thank you for all the inputs.